# LINQ Select: different projects same code different results

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-objects

The same code on two different web sites (on the same solution), VB.Net (framework 3.5).

The Code:

```
Public Class UserTest
    Public hhh As Integer
    Public fff As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal hh As Integer, ByVal ff As String)
        Me.hhh = hh
        Me.fff = ff
    End Sub

End Class

        Dim lst As List(Of UserTest) = New List(Of UserTest)
        lst.Add(New UserTest(1, "x"))
        lst.Add(New UserTest(2, "y"))

        Dim myData = lst.Select(Function(o) New With {.id = o.fff, .name = o.hhh})
```

One select returns property’s names with capital letters the other without.

[alt text http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/4509/linqbug1.jpg](http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/4509/linqbug1.jpg)

I tried changing the properties names and no capital letters at all.

```
Dim myData = lst.Select(Function(o) New With {.prop1 = o.fff, .prop2 = o.hhh})
```

[alt text http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/5231/linqbug2.jpg](http://img695.imageshack.us/img695/5231/linqbug2.jpg)

Thanks.

Comment: Output 1 and Output 2 are the same...

Comment: Is it possible that the other code uses different capitalization in the anonymous object constructor?

Comment: @Fabian - it's the property names that are different, not the data.

Comment: Can you show the StaticData class. Also, what's the impact of the difference in capitalisation to your app?

Comment: Lazarus, JavaScript is case-sensitive. Hence the two JSON objects are incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

In the code sample you posted, the property names in the anonymous object initializer are written with a lowercase first letter. Are you sure that the code in the other website is *really* the same ? I suspect it uses uppercase first letters :

```
Dim ggg = StaticData.GetLocationsByText(data, CountryId).Select( _
 Function(o) New With { _
 .Id = o.UniqueLocation, _
 .Text = o.DisplayLocation}).ToList()
```